# How to setup local Docker development with virtual host?

Tags: docker

I am using Docker for Windows and installed the Official Docker Image for WordPress. Is there a way to set up virtual hosts in local docker development in order to use named URLs e.g. mywpsite.dev as opposed to localhost:8080?

Comment: Do you want this to just work on your local machine only?  Or is it accessible from other locations?

Comment: @jrbeverly just on my local development machine

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the named virtual host is already in place.

You have 2 options:

1.Use DNS Server: If you have dns server on local network, just add `mywpsite.dev` A record and point it to Dockerhost's IP address.

2.Use Dockerhost's HostFile:

Openup your **hostsfile** on windows, and add an entry at the end:

```
mywpsite.dev xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is Dockerhost's IP address.